# Content size based grid layout

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid

I am trying to make a grid layout for cards like google keep has a grid layout.
screen shot for reference :
[image: Google Keep Screenshot]

Can anyone help me with the required css aur js , also i am using react.

Comment: You can do some research on     `column-count`       css property.

Comment: That's not a grid layout. It's a masonry layout. Google for that.